# Equality of two multilinear forms

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples, multilinear-algebra

Take two multilinear forms $f,g$ defined on the same set $E$ such that $\forall x\in E,f(x,x,\dots,x)=g(x,x,\dots,x)$.

Does that imply that the two functions are necessarily equal ?

I can't seem to find a counterexample, even for low dimensions .

Comment: I guess that a non supersymmetric tensor could be fine, isn't it?

Comment: @Surb Sorry, but I don't now what (non) supersymetric tensors are. I haven't learnt anything about tensors so far. Is there a simpler example of such objects ? Do you have a concrete example in mind ?

Comment: $f(x,y,z) = x_1y_2z_3$ and $g(x,y,z)=x_3y_2z_1$ for $x,y,z\in\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y) = x_1y_2\qquad \text{and}\qquad g(x,y)=y_1x_2\qquad \forall x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2)\in\Bbb R^2$$
Then $f(x,x)=g(x,x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^2$ but $f\neq g$.

Comment: note that $f(x,y)=x_1$ and $g(x,y)=y_1$ works also fine :)